# After installation of Oracle in silent mode, I am not able to run SQLPLUS

Tags: linux, oracle, installation, sqlplus

Showing the error

> /oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/bin/sqlplus: error while loading shared libraries: /oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/lib/libclntsh.so.12.1: file too short

```
[oracle@82eb40bf3cd2 ~]$ strace $ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus
execve("/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/bin/sqlplus", ["/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/"...], 0x7ffd4df2e550 /* 23 vars */) = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0xd63000
arch_prctl(0x3001 /* ARCH_??? */, 0x7fffa311c1b0) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/lib/tls/haswell/x86_64/libsqlplus.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/lib/tls/haswell/x86_64", 0x7fffa311b400) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/lib/tls/haswell/libsqlplus.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/lib/tls/haswell", 0x7fffa311b400) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/lib/tls/x86_64/libsqlplus.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/lib/tls/x86_64", 0x7fffa311b400) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/lib/tls/libsqlplus.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/lib/tls", 0x7fffa311b400) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/lib/haswell/x86_64/libsqlplus.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/lib/haswell/x86_64", 0x7fffa311b400) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/lib/haswell/libsqlplus.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/lib/haswell", 0x7fffa311b400) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/lib/x86_64/libsqlplus.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/lib/x86_64", 0x7fffa311b400) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/lib/libsqlplus.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\320\374\1\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1546540, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f664e6da000
mmap(NULL, 3112424, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f664e1bc000
mprotect(0x7f664e2a6000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f664e4a5000, 61440, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0xe9000) = 0x7f664e4a5000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/lib/libclntsh.so.12.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "", 832)                        = 0
close(3)                                = 0
writev(2, [{iov_base="/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/"..., iov_len=43}, {iov_base=": ", iov_len=2}, {iov_base="error while loading shared libra"..., iov_len=36}, {iov_base=": ", iov_len=2}, {iov_base="/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/"..., iov_len=53}, {iov_base=": ", iov_len=2}, {iov_base="file too short", iov_len=14}, {iov_base="", iov_len=0}, {iov_base="", iov_len=0}, {iov_base="\n", iov_len=1}], 10/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/bin/sqlplus: error while loading shared libraries: /oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/lib/libclntsh.so.12.1: file too short
) = 153
exit_group(127)                         = ?
+++ exited with 127 +++
```

Comment: ls -l /oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/lib/libclntsh.so.12.1

Comment: What is Linux release and Oracle 12.1.0.X release?

Comment: [root@82eb40bf3cd2 installer]# ls -l /oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/lib/libclntsh.so.12.1
-rwxr-xr-x 1 oracle oracle 0 Oct 24 09:20 /oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/lib/libclntsh.so.12.1

Comment: linux release - Centos 8.0 and oracle release is 12.1.0.2

Answer (score 1):

This error comes mostly due to missing rpm packages glib-devel on the system.
On my system the issue got resolved after below operations:

1. Installing the correct rpm for glib
2. Then run this command to recreate all the symlinks.
   $ORACLE_HOME/bin/relink all
3. Try sqlplus now.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to install oracle on an unsupported platform. Your version of oracle 12.1.0.2 supports linux 7.  At present the Oracle database is not supported on Linux 8.
[Unofficially Oracle Database 19c Installation On Oracle Linux 8 (OL8)](https://oracle-base.com/articles/19c/oracle-db-19c-installation-on-oracle-linux-8)

[Oracle Linux 7 and Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 Support Information on Linux x86-64](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LADBN/toc.htm#LADBN101)

> Starting with Oracle Database 12c Release 1 (12.1.0.2), Oracle Linux 7
>   and Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 are supported on Linux x86-64 systems.
>
> Starting with Oracle Database 12c Release 1 (12.1.0.2), Oracle Linux 7
>   is supported on the following distributions for Linux x86-64:
>
> Oracle Linux 7 with the Unbreakable Enterprise kernel:
>   4.1.12-61.el7uek.x86_64 or later
>
> Oracle Linux 7 with the Unbreakable Enterprise kernel:
>   3.8.13-33.el7uek.x86_64 or later
>
> Oracle Linux 7 with the Red Hat Compatible kernel:
>   3.10.0-123.el7.x86_64 or later

[Operating System Checklist for Oracle Database 19c Installation on Linux](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/ladbi/operating-system-checklist-for-oracle-database-installation-on-linux.html#GUID-E5C0A90E-7750-45D9-A8BC-C7319ED934F0)

> The following Linux x86-64 kernels are supported:
>
> Oracle Linux 7.4 with the Unbreakable Enterprise Kernel 4:
>   4.1.12-124.19.2.el7uek.x86_64 or later Oracle Linux 7.4 with the Unbreakable Enterprise Kernel 5: 4.14.35-1818.1.6.el7uek.x86_64 or
>   later Oracle Linux 7.5 with the Red Hat Compatible kernel:
>   3.10.0-862.11.6.el7.x86_64 or later
>
> Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.5: 3.10.0-862.11.6.el7.x86_64 or later
>
> SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 12 SP3: 4.4.162-94.72-default or later
>
> SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 15: 4.12.14-23-default or later
>
> Review the system requirements section for a list of minimum package
>   requirements.

Comment: [oracle@0dd087a75e9f bin]$ sqlplus
sqlplus: error while loading shared libraries: /home/oracle/lib/libclntsh.so.12.1: file too short